# Ubuntu server 18.04 - keep loading stuff at login

Tags: server, login

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu server 18.04 installed.
I tried both with a pre-installed machine, and a manual installed one...

Once I get to the login screen, the system does not allow me to insert my user/password because of some more messages on the screen. 
It seems like it's still loading stuff instead of waiting for my credentials.

See attached screenshot at https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbeetm335havrqn/ubuntu.JPG?dl=0

It's really annoying! Anyone have the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification: Have you tried to enter your credentials anyway, simply ignoring the messages? (this should be a comment, but my reputation's too low)

Comment: I disabled Cloud Server feature via tasksel, now the problem seems disappeared.

Comment: Just for clarification: inserting credentials ignoring all messages may work... but not always. Sometimes message keep showing also when user is logged in.

Everything's fine turning off the Cloud server.